# Looking for a robust and complete fltk and tk based window managers and file managers

Tags: tk-toolkit, fltk

I came across two least known window managers and file managers more suited for freebsd, and based on entirely different api, i.e. fltk and tk:

1) flwm (fltk window manager) and whim (tkwm, tk window manager).

2) flfm/mfm file manager and tkDesk file manager.

Found that they were among the least mentioned.

Are there any more robust and complete desktops and file managers created with fltk and tk?

Comment: This is not a good type of question for Stack Overflow, as it doesn't admit a proper correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is the EDE, aka the Equinox Desktop Environment - http://www.equinox-project.org . It is a fairly active project and is included in many Linux/BSD distributions.

Comment: Oh, equinox looks new and impressive. Ok, it is based on fltk toolkit. Which is the default file manager for equinox -- flfm, or mfm, or something else?